# How do I make a table stand vertically? MS Word for Mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-word, table-styles

I need to make a table stand vertically (otherwise it will not fit on one page). How do I do this? I have text surrounding the table.

Vertical: Usually, the contents of a table that is horizontal run horizontally across the page. Just as these lines of word do. In a vertical table, the words run from bottom up.

This is not the same as transposing. As if one would rotate the table 90 degrees to the right.

Comment: Define "stand vertically."

Comment: Do you mean how do you transpose a Word table (i.e., from 2x10 to 10x2)?

Comment: What orientation of the letters are you looking for (stacked vertical letters or everything rotated like turning a photo of the table 90 degrees)?  Also, typically when you rotate something like a table, it is done counter-clockwise.  When you say "to the right", do you mean clockwise?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it’s impossible to have horizontal text and vertical text
on the same page of a Word document — at least not in a useful sense. 
You’ll need to have the table on a page by itself. 
To do this, insert Section Breaks (Next Page)
immediately before and after the table (i.e., before and after the table
and any associated titles or captions that you want to appear with the table). 
Do this by going to the “Page Layout” tab, “Page Setup” panel,
click on “Breaks”, and select “Next Page” from the bottom part
of the menu that pops up. 
Then click somewhere in the page with the table on it,
and (also in the “Page Setup” panel)
click on “Orientation” and select “Landscape”.

Note: These instructions are based on Word 2007 / Word 2013 on Windows.